# XSD restricting the number of children for a partent element

Tags: xml, xsd

So I am trying to define a schema for an XML file that we will be using in a program. There is an element that has children that defines the source language and any target languages for the entire file. There is always only 1 source language, and it must be the same in every translationUnit. There can be any number of targetLanguages, but every translationUnit must have the exact same targetLanguages, they can't be different.

Is there a way in XSD or another schema format to:

a) Require that the langLocale of the sourceSegment of each of the translationUnits is the same as the sourceLang in the jobLanguages element?

b) Require that the langLocale attribute of the targetSegment elements of each of the translationUnits match the langLocales of the targetLang elements of the jobLanguages element?

Essentially, each request sent with the XML has to be consistent throughout the entire document, some translationUnits cannot have a different source language or a different set of target languages.

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translationBody>
    <translationJob>
        <jobLanguages>
            <sourceLang>en-US</sourceLang>
            <targetLang>ja-JP</targetLang>
            <targetLang>ko-KR</targetLang>
            <targetLang>es-ES</targetLang>
            <targetLang>de-DE</targetLang>
            <targetLang>fr-FR</targetLang>
            <targetLang>ru-RU</targetLang>
            <targetLang>zh-CN</targetLang>
            <targetLang>zh-TW</targetLang>
            <targetLang>ar-AA</targetLang>
        </jobLanguages>
        <translationUnit active="true" key="introText" notes="Notes for translator" lenRestriction="25">
            <sourceSegment langLocale="en-US">Some text for translation.</sourceSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ja-JP">翻訳用テキスト</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ko-KR">번역을위한 일부 텍스트"</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="es-ES">Algunos textos para traducción</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="de-DE">Irgendein Text für Übersetzung</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="fr-FR">Quelques textes pour la traduction</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ru-RU">Некоторый текст для перевода</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-CN">一些翻译文字</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-TW">一些翻譯文字</targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ar-AA">بعض النصوص للترجمة</targetSegment>
        </translationUnit>
        <translationUnit active="true" key="headerText" notes="Notes for translator">
            <sourceSegment langLocale="en-US">New text for translation.</sourceSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ja-JP"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ko-KR"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="es-ES"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="de-DE"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="fr-FR"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ru-RU"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-CN"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-TW"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ar-AA"></targetSegment>
        </translationUnit>
        <translationUnit active="false" key="buttonText" notes="Text that is no longer active">
            <sourceSegment langLocale="en-US">New text for translation.</sourceSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ja-JP"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ko-KR"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="es-ES"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="de-DE"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="fr-FR"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ru-RU"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-CN"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="zh-TW"></targetSegment>
            <targetSegment langLocale="ar-AA"></targetSegment>
        </translationUnit>
    </translationJob>
</translationBody>
```

Current XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:simpleType name="sourceString">
    <xs:annotation id="SourceStringDesc"><xs:documentation>This is a type setup to ensure that the length of the sourcString is greater than 0. Essentially, it is not ok to have a blank sourceSegment.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="langString">
    <xs:annotation id="langStringDesc"><xs:documentation>This is a type setup to ensure that the length of the langString is greater than 0. Essentially, it is not ok to have a blank langString.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      <xs:pattern value="da-DK|ms-MY|it-IT|pt-BR|zh-CN|es-US|ko-KR|fr-CA|pt-PT|fr-FR|ja-JP|es-ES|de-DE|en-US|ru-RU|es-419|en-GB|zh-TW|tr-TR|nl-NL|th-TH|az-AZ-Cyrl|az-AZ-Latn|ba-RU|eu-ES|hmv|br-FR|bg-BG|my-BU|cal|ca-ES|ceb|ch|ny-MW|am-ET|zh-HK|zh-SG|bn|fr|fu|hr-HR|cs-CZ|ht|prs-AF|en|bal-IR|en-AU|eo|en-BZ|en-CA|en-CB|en-IE|en-JM|en-NZ|en-PH|en-ZA|en-CH|en-TT|en-ZW|et-EE|fo-FO|fa-IR|fj-FJ|sm-WS|fr-BE|nl|ar-DZ|mh|ar-AA|as-IN|ab|fy|fr-LU|ik|fr-MC|tet-ID|fr-CH|gd-GB|gl-ES|ka-GE|ar-IQ|ar-LY|ar-LB|ar-JO|ga-IE|lv-LV|ar-KW|he-IL|ar-MA|de-AT|sla-ME|de-LU|pau|de-CH|el-GR|kl-GL|grn|is-IS|es|ha-NG|hi-IN|id-ID|ia|ie|iu|zu-ZA|kk-KZ|jv-ID|kn-IN|ks|lo-LA|rw-RW|kg-CG|kok-IN|ku-TR|ln-CG|lt-LT|lb|mk-MK|mg-MG|mt-MT|mi-NZ|mn-MN|na-NR|nd-ZW|nb-NO|nn-NO|oc-FR|ps|pl-PL|qu-PE|ro-RO|rn|sg|sa-IN|sr-CY|sr-LA|sr-YU|st|sn|it-CH|ne-NP|pa-PA|ml-IN|yi|la|mo-MD|mr-IN|sk-SK|sl-SI|ar-OM|ar-QA|es-CU|ar-SA|apd-SD|ar-SY|sd|syr-TR|so-DJ|so-ET|tk-TM|so-KE|so-SO|dsb-DE|hsb-DE|es-AR|es-BO|es-CL|es-CO|es-CR|es-EC|es-SV|es-GT|es-HN|es-MX|es-NI|es-PA|es-PY|es-PE|es-PR|rm-CH|be-BY|so|sv|tt-RU|cy-GB|yi-IL|yo-NG|ta-IN|te-IN|ar-TN|bo|es-UY|es-VE|su|sw-KE|ss|sv-FI|sv-SE|tl-PH|tg-TJ|ts-ZA|tn-BW|uz-UZ-Latn|tn-ZA|tw|ug-CN|uk-UA|ur-IN|vi-VN|vo|xh-ZA|za|gu-IN|km-KH|zh-MO|or-IN|co-FR|de-LI|it|no|nl-BE|si-LK|de|pt|sq-AL|tz|nai|ti|ky|CHR|fil|nso-ZA|wo|fr-SN|ig|en-SG|ps-IR|to-TO|en-IN|ls|bs-BS-Cyrl|om-ET|hy-AM|dv-IN|fi-FI|hu-HU|es-DO|bs-BS-Latn|aa-ET|af-ZA|ar-BH|ar-EG|bn_IN|bn_BD|bi-VU|ar-AE|ar-YE"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="translationBody">
    <xs:annotation id="translationBodyDesc"><xs:documentation>This is the main body of the translation text. There are no allowed attributes or restrictions. There must be at least one translationUnit element.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="translationJob" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="jobLanguages" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
               <xs:annotation>
                 <xs:documentation>This element encapsulates the languages for the project. All the languages listed here should match the languages indicated in each translationUnit.</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="sourceLang" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
               <xs:annotation>
                 <xs:documentation>This element encapsulates the source language of the project, and should match the source language of each translationUnit. There can and must be only 1 of these elements</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:simpleContent>
                   <xs:extension base="langString">
                   </xs:extension>
                 </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="targetLang" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
               <xs:annotation>
                 <xs:documentation>This element encapsulates the target languages of the project. Each translationUnit should have each of these target languages, no exceptions. There must be at least 1 targetLanguage specified, but there is no limit as to how many targetLanguages there can be. Each target language must be unique, and the targetLanguage should not equal the sourceLanguage.</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:simpleContent>
                   <xs:extension base="langString">
                   </xs:extension>
                 </xs:simpleContent>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
                 </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
               <xs:unique name="uniqueJobLangs">
                 <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
                 <xs:field xpath="@langString"/>
               </xs:unique>
             </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="translationUnit" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
          <xs:annotation id="translationUnitDesc"><xs:documentation>This is the main unit for translation and comprises language combination(s). There should be only one sourceSegment element, and at least one targetSegment element. The langLocale attribute on each targetSegment element must be unique. In other words, there can only be one targetSegment per language. Also, no targetSegment can have the same langLocale as the sourceSegment. If no translation exists yet, targetSegments should be left blank, but they MUST be included in the file</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="sourceSegment" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:annotation id="sourceSegmentDesc"><xs:documentation>Text for translation is placed in this element. Must be 1 per translationUnit element. Cannot be null, also cannot be less than 1 character long.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="sourceString">
                      <xs:attribute name="langLocale" use="required">
                        <xs:annotation id="langLocaleDesc"><xs:documentation>This is the language-locale combination for the source. All sourceString must have the same langLocale</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:annotation id="langRestrictionDesc"><xs:documentation>The available options for language locale combos are limited certain values based on our API. Please see Glyph Best Practices API Documentation for more details.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                            <xs:pattern value="da-DK|ms-MY|it-IT|pt-BR|zh-CN|es-US|ko-KR|fr-CA|pt-PT|fr-FR|ja-JP|es-ES|de-DE|en-US|ru-RU|es-419|en-GB|zh-TW|tr-TR|nl-NL|th-TH|az-AZ-Cyrl|az-AZ-Latn|ba-RU|eu-ES|hmv|br-FR|bg-BG|my-BU|cal|ca-ES|ceb|ch|ny-MW|am-ET|zh-HK|zh-SG|bn|fr|fu|hr-HR|cs-CZ|ht|prs-AF|en|bal-IR|en-AU|eo|en-BZ|en-CA|en-CB|en-IE|en-JM|en-NZ|en-PH|en-ZA|en-CH|en-TT|en-ZW|et-EE|fo-FO|fa-IR|fj-FJ|sm-WS|fr-BE|nl|ar-DZ|mh|ar-AA|as-IN|ab|fy|fr-LU|ik|fr-MC|tet-ID|fr-CH|gd-GB|gl-ES|ka-GE|ar-IQ|ar-LY|ar-LB|ar-JO|ga-IE|lv-LV|ar-KW|he-IL|ar-MA|de-AT|sla-ME|de-LU|pau|de-CH|el-GR|kl-GL|grn|is-IS|es|ha-NG|hi-IN|id-ID|ia|ie|iu|zu-ZA|kk-KZ|jv-ID|kn-IN|ks|lo-LA|rw-RW|kg-CG|kok-IN|ku-TR|ln-CG|lt-LT|lb|mk-MK|mg-MG|mt-MT|mi-NZ|mn-MN|na-NR|nd-ZW|nb-NO|nn-NO|oc-FR|ps|pl-PL|qu-PE|ro-RO|rn|sg|sa-IN|sr-CY|sr-LA|sr-YU|st|sn|it-CH|ne-NP|pa-PA|ml-IN|yi|la|mo-MD|mr-IN|sk-SK|sl-SI|ar-OM|ar-QA|es-CU|ar-SA|apd-SD|ar-SY|sd|syr-TR|so-DJ|so-ET|tk-TM|so-KE|so-SO|dsb-DE|hsb-DE|es-AR|es-BO|es-CL|es-CO|es-CR|es-EC|es-SV|es-GT|es-HN|es-MX|es-NI|es-PA|es-PY|es-PE|es-PR|rm-CH|be-BY|so|sv|tt-RU|cy-GB|yi-IL|yo-NG|ta-IN|te-IN|ar-TN|bo|es-UY|es-VE|su|sw-KE|ss|sv-FI|sv-SE|tl-PH|tg-TJ|ts-ZA|tn-BW|uz-UZ-Latn|tn-ZA|tw|ug-CN|uk-UA|ur-IN|vi-VN|vo|xh-ZA|za|gu-IN|km-KH|zh-MO|or-IN|co-FR|de-LI|it|no|nl-BE|si-LK|de|pt|sq-AL|tz|nai|ti|ky|CHR|fil|nso-ZA|wo|fr-SN|ig|en-SG|ps-IR|to-TO|en-IN|ls|bs-BS-Cyrl|om-ET|hy-AM|dv-IN|fi-FI|hu-HU|es-DO|bs-BS-Latn|aa-ET|af-ZA|ar-BH|ar-EG|bn_IN|bn_BD|bi-VU|ar-AE|ar-YE"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="targetSegment" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" nillable="true">
                <xs:annotation id="targetSegmentDesc"><xs:documentation>This is the element that holds any translated text or is the place holder for translated text. It can be empty, but there must be at least one in each translationUnit. In other words, there must be at least one language combination in the file.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute name="langLocale" use="required">
                        <xs:annotation id="langLocaleDesc2"><xs:documentation>This is the language-locale combination for the source. All sourceString must have the same langLocale</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:annotation id="langRestrictionDesc2"><xs:documentation>The available options for language locale combos are limited certain values based on our API. Please see Glyph Best Practices API Documentation for more details.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
                            <xs:pattern value="da-DK|ms-MY|it-IT|pt-BR|zh-CN|es-US|ko-KR|fr-CA|pt-PT|fr-FR|ja-JP|es-ES|de-DE|en-US|ru-RU|es-419|en-GB|zh-TW|tr-TR|nl-NL|th-TH|az-AZ-Cyrl|az-AZ-Latn|ba-RU|eu-ES|hmv|br-FR|bg-BG|my-BU|cal|ca-ES|ceb|ch|ny-MW|am-ET|zh-HK|zh-SG|bn|fr|fu|hr-HR|cs-CZ|ht|prs-AF|en|bal-IR|en-AU|eo|en-BZ|en-CA|en-CB|en-IE|en-JM|en-NZ|en-PH|en-ZA|en-CH|en-TT|en-ZW|et-EE|fo-FO|fa-IR|fj-FJ|sm-WS|fr-BE|nl|ar-DZ|mh|ar-AA|as-IN|ab|fy|fr-LU|ik|fr-MC|tet-ID|fr-CH|gd-GB|gl-ES|ka-GE|ar-IQ|ar-LY|ar-LB|ar-JO|ga-IE|lv-LV|ar-KW|he-IL|ar-MA|de-AT|sla-ME|de-LU|pau|de-CH|el-GR|kl-GL|grn|is-IS|es|ha-NG|hi-IN|id-ID|ia|ie|iu|zu-ZA|kk-KZ|jv-ID|kn-IN|ks|lo-LA|rw-RW|kg-CG|kok-IN|ku-TR|ln-CG|lt-LT|lb|mk-MK|mg-MG|mt-MT|mi-NZ|mn-MN|na-NR|nd-ZW|nb-NO|nn-NO|oc-FR|ps|pl-PL|qu-PE|ro-RO|rn|sg|sa-IN|sr-CY|sr-LA|sr-YU|st|sn|it-CH|ne-NP|pa-PA|ml-IN|yi|la|mo-MD|mr-IN|sk-SK|sl-SI|ar-OM|ar-QA|es-CU|ar-SA|apd-SD|ar-SY|sd|syr-TR|so-DJ|so-ET|tk-TM|so-KE|so-SO|dsb-DE|hsb-DE|es-AR|es-BO|es-CL|es-CO|es-CR|es-EC|es-SV|es-GT|es-HN|es-MX|es-NI|es-PA|es-PY|es-PE|es-PR|rm-CH|be-BY|so|sv|tt-RU|cy-GB|yi-IL|yo-NG|ta-IN|te-IN|ar-TN|bo|es-UY|es-VE|su|sw-KE|ss|sv-FI|sv-SE|tl-PH|tg-TJ|ts-ZA|tn-BW|uz-UZ-Latn|tn-ZA|tw|ug-CN|uk-UA|ur-IN|vi-VN|vo|xh-ZA|za|gu-IN|km-KH|zh-MO|or-IN|co-FR|de-LI|it|no|nl-BE|si-LK|de|pt|sq-AL|tz|nai|ti|ky|CHR|fil|nso-ZA|wo|fr-SN|ig|en-SG|ps-IR|to-TO|en-IN|ls|bs-BS-Cyrl|om-ET|hy-AM|dv-IN|fi-FI|hu-HU|es-DO|bs-BS-Latn|aa-ET|af-ZA|ar-BH|ar-EG|bn_IN|bn_BD|bi-VU|ar-AE|ar-YE"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="active" use="required">
              <xs:annotation id="activeDesc"><xs:documentation>This indicates whether this translationUnit is active. If you do not want this to be translated or processed, set to false. Default should be true</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="true"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="false"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="key" use="required">
            <xs:annotation id="keyDesc"><xs:documentation>key is a required element. It should be a unique identifier for your string.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="notes" use="required">
                <xs:annotation id="notesDesc"><xs:documentation>The notes attribute MUST be included, even if it is left blank (=""). Put any notes about context or information the translators should know. The notes will be presented to all langauges. At this time, we don't support langauge specific notes.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
              </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="lenRestriction" use="required">
              <xs:annotation id="lenRestrictionDesc"><xs:documentation>The notes attribute MUST be included, and cannot be left blank. The value should be 0 if no length restriction is desired. This attribute is used to tells the translator the maximum number of characters allowed for this string. If used, it must be an integer of 1 or greater. If used, the translator will be forced to validate the length or change their translation prior to delivery.</xs:documentation></xs:annotation>
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction>
                  <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:unique name="uniqueLang">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@langLocale"/>
          </xs:unique>
          <xs:unique name="uniqueKey">
            <xs:selector xpath="*"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@key"></xs:field>
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight it certainly looks as if this can be done with key/keyref.

At the level of translationJob, define a key with selection=jobLanguages/sourceLang, field=".", and a corresponding keyref with selection translationUnit/sourceSegment, field=@langLocale.

Then define a second key with selection=jobLanguages/targetLang (field="."), and a corresponding keyRef with selection=translationUnit/targetSegment, field=@langLocale.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is great information. It gets me almost there. It makes sure that the source and target languages are limited to those defined in the jobLanguages section. However, it doesn't enforce that each translationUnit has the same number of target languages as the targetLangs in jobLanguages. So for instance, if one translationUnit only has 4 targetLanguages instead of the 5 set in the jobLanguages, it passes validation.

Any thoughts on how to force one element to have the same number of children as another?

Comment: I think that for that requirement you would need XSD 1.1 assertions.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am thinking, so if I converted to XSD 1.1, and used something like <xs:assert test="count(jobLanguages/targetLang) eq count(translationUnit/targetSegment)" />, placed right before the ending xs:complexType tag of the translationJob element, should that do it? I am trying that and for some reason it is still validating even if I omit one of the languages in a translationUnit.

Comment: Actually, I think that I just figured it out. I ended up changing the assertion to "<xs:assert test="count(jobLanguage/targetLang) eq (count(translationUnit/targetSegment) div count(translationUnit))" />. maybe not the most elegant, but it works. Thanks so much for getting me in the right direction.